# c# Date format not showing local format

Tags: c#, date-format

On my local machine, my Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture returns the correct local culture (en-GB).  The date format is set to yyyy-MM-dd.

In code, when I run:

```
value.ToShortDateString()
```

it returns `"6/2/2010"`  (m/d/yyyy).

How can I get it to display according the the local culture?  I do not want to hard code a format as the app will be deployed in different countries, so it should work according to the local pc setup.  I've also tested on a en-US and it displays the same.

The value of my 'value' variable is:

```
{6/2/2010 12:00:00 AM}
    Date: {6/2/2010 12:00:00 AM}
    Day: 2
    DayOfWeek: Wednesday
    DayOfYear: 153
    Hour: 0
    Kind: Unspecified
    Millisecond: 0
    Minute: 0
    Month: 6
    Second: 0
    Ticks: 634110336000000000
    TimeOfDay: {00:00:00}
    Year: 2010
```

Comment: value.ToShortDateString() return dynamic format only depending on local desktop configuration. Check out my answer for more explanation.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You say; your `CurrentCulture` is `en-GB` and asking _How can I get it to display according the the local culture?_. You _already_ did it with `ToShortDateString`. What do you want as a result exactly? In `yyyy-MM-dd` format instead? And `m` specifier is for minutes, `M` specifier is for months. Format specifiers are case sensitive.

Comment: @Soner: ToShortDateString returns the US format 6/2/2010.  i would like it to return according to the local culture i.e. 2010-06-02.

Answer (score 3):

Simply call `ToString()` rather than `ToShortDateString()` and specify your date format:

```
    DateTimeFormatInfo formatInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat;
    var value = DateTime.Now.ToString(formatInfo);
```

Though `ToShortDateString()` should be culture-sensitive [as per the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The value of the current DateTime object is formatted using the pattern defined by the DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortDatePattern property associated with the current thread culture. The return value is identical to the value returned by specifying the "d" standard DateTime format string with the ToString(String) method.

However, it could return the wrong format if the CurrentCulture and the CurrentUICulture differ. To be safe, I've made it use the CurrentUICulture in the code sample, as it is based on the user's UI culture settings - e.g. UK language pack on US system etc. and should be correct.

Comment: Tx - I probably should have said it in the question, but it needs to dynamic on the culture.  When we deploy in other countries we don't want it to be hard coded.  I'll update the question.

Comment: @user1208908 Updated the answer to take this into account.

Comment: I've tried your solution and it returns "4/22/2015 2:43:01 PM", which is still the US format.

Comment: @user1208908 What is your CurrentUICulture set to? en-US or en-UK?

Comment: @user1208908 Weird, `DateTimeFormatInfo formatInfo = new CultureInfo("en-GB").DateTimeFormat;` using `DateTime.Now.ToString` with that CultureInfo returns the (correct) date for me: 22/4.

Comment: It will return the correct format as the culture is hard coded which is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the culture in your ToString():

```
DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: The solution returns "2/18/2014 12:00:00 AM".  Still the wrong format.

Answer (score 1):

The `ToShortDateString` method *should* be culture sensitve - the format it uses is governed by the `DateTimeFormatInfo` object of the current culture. Have you checked this is what you would expect?

(This should really be a comment as it's not a definite answer/fix - unfortunately I don't have sufficient reputation to comment.)

Comment: This is what I was about to submit as per reading this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) . Have an upvote to get you on your way to being able to comment...

Answer (score 0):

> A Simple call to `ToShortDateString()` takes *input format* from local
>   desktop. It will display date string as configured in local windows
>   desktop.

- If local config is 15/4/22 (yy/m/dd), output will be 15/4/22
- If local config is 4/22/2015 (m/dd/yyyy), output will be 4/22/2015

> local config can be changed under change date and time setting >>
>   change calendar setting >> Change Date format

(When I mention local configuration, I meant date format displayed in right bottom of task bar in windows.)

Comment: Well, that's how it is suppose to work, and that's partly the reason for the question.  It does not show the date in that format.

Comment: Which .net version you are using ? It is working exactly same as described at my place.

Comment: Visual Studio Professional 2013